# Close $mdDialog from different component

Tags: angularjs, typescript, material-design

I have a button in my `CardKnowledgeDB.html`

```
<button ng-click="vm.launchContactActivityPopup()">Contact</button>
```

It calls this function in my `CardKnowledgeDBComponent.ts`

```
public launchContactActivityPopup(): void {
    this.$mdDialog.show({
        template: `
            <md-dialog class="add-contact-moment-popup">
                <register-contact-activity-popup></register-contact-activity-popup>
            </md-dialog>`,
        targetEvent: null,
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
    });
}

public cancel(): void {
    this.$mdDialog.cancel();
}
```

I have a `ResponsiveNavigation` component that has a `a href` button inside the template to return to the homepage. When I click it and return to the homepage I want to close the current `$mdDialog`.

So how do I reference the `$mdDialog` that's in the `CardKnowLedgeDBComponent.ts` from my `ResponsiveNavigationComponent.ts`?

Or is there a global way to close all `$mdDialog` views?

// EDIT // ANWSER

You can just add

```
public removeMdDialog() {
    this.$mdDialog.cancel();
}
```

(and Inject the `mdDialog`) and you have a global function to close a `$mdDialog`.